# Simulate different C Runtime for testing DLL-Interfaces

Tags: visual-c++, dll, crt

I'm currently working on a project that will be migrated to dynamic linking from static linking.

As multiple shared libraries will act as plugins, our plan is to allocate data that is shared between these plugins in the main executable instead of in each shared library.

Now I got multiple questions:

1. Regarding memory allocation and deallocation: Should I get errors if I allocate memory in the shared library and delete it in the exe (and the other way around)? On Windows I do not get any errors. Does this problem only occur between shared libraries or does this problem not occur because I'm linking to the same CRT?
2. Is there a way to force a different CRT for a DLL so that I can test my DLL Memory allocations/deallocations?
3. Are there frameworks available designed for testing C Interfaces and memory allocations across DLL boundaries?

Comment: All your DLLs need to use the dynamic runtime support DLLs and they must all use the same version(s).